# python3 calling python2 package when python3 package also available

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

(Using ubuntu 16.04)

Several times already I've run into the following problem:

- I have two versions of the same package 'package', for python2 and python3
- In a virtual environment that defaults to python3 I run python my_program.py which does 'import package'
- Python then goes to the folder for python2 version of the package and fails because it's written in python2. Some example error:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpi4py/MPI.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

When I'm desperate to run it immediately I just go and remove the package manually (here I would do: `sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mpi4y`). Then python goes to the python3 version of the package and runs smoothly.

This is clearly not the correct long-term solution. What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: it looks like your `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` is also part of the sys.path of your python 3 distro. have you made changes to your config?

Comment: You say you are using virtualenvs, but this should not happen in a virtualenv. Are you sure you have activated it veggie running your script?